# custom error firing when there has been no error, but only in IIS6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-6

I have written this site in MVC4 and hosting it on an IIS6. 
I call this on method when an error occurs through customerror in the web.config.

```
public ActionResult Error()
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        return View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml");
    }
```

but it fires when there is no error but it only fires the session.abandon() and not the return view(). If I comment out the session.abandon() it works fine, the rest of my site runs and there have been no errors, with it though I get an exception that my session has expired but as this code should not fire I don't get why.

On IIS7 this works fine.

Anyone got any idea as to what is happening?

Comment: Can you give us some more information, what OS are you running?

Comment: The OS is windows 2003